# (tidyverse) Extract substring groupwise for each string in column given positions to include

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe of DNA alignments. Each alignment has a label and could be composed of 3 or more isolates. My goal is to mutate the alignment column to **get rid of positions that are all gaps (denoted by "-") in isolate 1, 3, and 4** for each alignment. All alignments will always have isolates 1,3, and 4 in them, and sometimes only those three will be in the alignment.

**what I have:**

```
test_df <- data.frame(isolate=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),label=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),alignment=c("--atc-a","at----a","--ataga","--attga","a---ggg","acgttgg","a---tgg","a---tgg", "aggatgg"))

> test_df
  isolate label alignment
1       1     1   --atc-a
2       2     1   at----a
3       3     1   --ataga
4       4     1   --attga
5       1     2   a---ggg
6       2     2   acgttgg
7       3     2   a---tgg
8       4     2   a---tgg
9       5     2   aggatgg
```

**what I want:**

```
> test_df
  isolate label alignment
1       1     1   atc-a
2       2     1   ----a
3       3     1   ataga
4       4     1   attga
5       1     2   aggg
6       2     2   atgg
7       3     2   atgg
8       4     2   atgg
9       5     2   atgg
```

**what I've tried:**

I can get a list of sites that I want to keep for each alignment like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
test_df %>% 
    mutate(positions=str_locate_all(alignment, "[^-]")) %>%
    group_by(label) %>%
    filter(isolate %in% c(1,3,4)) %>%
    summarise(pos_to_keep=list(unique(unlist(Reduce(rbind, positions)))))
```

but then I'm not sure how to proceed in order to slice all the alignments.

Comment: imo it is a bit unclear how you are getting your expected outcome. Could you explain in words how `--atc-a` goes to `atc-a`, and  `at----a` to `----a` etc please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way I could get to your solution. There might be quicker way out there.

```
library(dplyr)
test_df <- data.frame(isolate=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),label=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),alignment=c("--atc-a","at----a","--ataga","--attga","a---ggg","acgttgg","a---tgg","a---tgg", "aggatgg"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get the correct positions
labelGroups <- test_df %>% mutate(positions=(str_locate_all(alignment, "[^-]"))) %>% filter(isolate %in% c(1,3,4)) %>% group_by(label) %>% summarise(pos_to_keep=list(unique(sort(unlist(positions)))))

# Make a function to extract the relevant letters
getletters <- function(wordlist,indexlist){n <- length(indexlist);lapply(1:n,function(i) paste0(sapply(indexlist[[i]], function(x) substr(wordlist[i],x,x)),collapse=""))}

# Try it
test_df %>% left_join(labelGroups,by="label") %>% mutate(newAlignment=getletters(alignment,pos_to_keep))

# isolate label alignment   pos_to_keep newAlignment
# 1       1     1   --atc-a 3, 4, 5, 6, 7        atc-a
# 2       2     1   at----a 3, 4, 5, 6, 7        ----a
# 3       3     1   --ataga 3, 4, 5, 6, 7        ataga
# 4       4     1   --attga 3, 4, 5, 6, 7        attga
# 5       1     2   a---ggg    1, 5, 6, 7         aggg
# 6       2     2   acgttgg    1, 5, 6, 7         atgg
# 7       3     2   a---tgg    1, 5, 6, 7         atgg
# 8       4     2   a---tgg    1, 5, 6, 7         atgg
# 9       5     2   aggatgg    1, 5, 6, 7         atgg
```

Comment: @elsherbini That's awesome! Glad I could help.